# C++ set find value smaller but closer to x

Tags: c++, set

I looked at `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` in the C++ STL for `<set>`. I can't find a method, however, to get the value closest (from below) to another one in the set. Is there a simple way to get that or do I have to iterate the set?

As an example, say my set contains the following integers `3 4 7 9`, then `closest(6) = 4` and `closest(4) = 4`.

Comment: Once you have `lower_bound`, can't you just check the two neighbours?

Comment: Easier is `upper_bound() - 1`: upper_bound() is certain to point to the greater element, so only the case where the result points to the first element should be taken into account, when closest has no result (e.g. `closest(2)`.

Comment: @stefaanv: I'm not sure what you mean. lower_bound and upper_bound only give you different results if there are duplicate elements in the (sorted) collection, and you are looking for that particular element value.

Comment: but if the set is (4, 5, 6, 7) upper_bound(6) - 1 returns 6 and thats not what he wants is it?

Comment: @Bathsheba: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/upper_bound specifies "Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key", did I miss anything.  I'm not working with this on a daily basis.

Comment: @Dirk: `closest(4) = 4`: I thought that also was the case for 6.

Comment: @stefaanv either the 'closest(4) = 4' is wrong or the headline

Comment: @DavidGomes: could you clarify what is the expected result?

Comment: @stefaanv: You're right -- I had garbled the post in my head to mean that "closest(6) should be 7", though that's not what the OP wrote!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) returns an element greater than the given value, so in your case, your would have to decrement it to get the value before it.

```
//Returns value of element before 'num'
int closest = *--set.upper_bound(num);
```

---

I would have thought that `closest(6) = 7`, because `7` is closer to `6` than `4`. If you want to get `7`, you would have to calculate the difference between the adjacent values and compare them.

```
//Calculate closest value to 'num' in a std::set<int>
int closest(std::set<int>& set, int num)
{
    //Get iterator to element greater than 'num'
    auto it = set.upper_bound(num);

    //Check if 'it' is the 'end' iterator
    if (it == std::end(set))
        return 0;

    int valueLeft = *it--; //Get value of the greater element
    int valueRight = *it; //Get value of the element before (due to post-decrement)

    //Compare diffence between value less and num, and value greater and num
    if (valueLeft - num > num - valueRight)
        return valueRight;
    else
        return valueLeft;
}

std::set<int> set{ 3, 4, 7, 9 };

int a = closest(set, 6); //Returns '7'
int b = closest(set, 4); //Returns '4'
```

Comment: In the `upper_case` answer, the 'not found' case should be handled by not crashing.

Comment: `std::upper_bound` is inefficent on a set. You could be using `std::set::upper_bound` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this generic algorithm:

```
template <typename Set>
typename Set::const_iterator
find_closest(Set const & s, typename Set::value_type const & val)
{
    auto a = s.begin(), b = s.end(), it = s.lower_bound(val);

    if (it == b) 
    {
        if (it != a) --it;
        return it;
    }

    auto nt = std::next(it);

    if (nt == b) return it;
    return val - *it < *nt - val ? it : nt;
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could explain why you pre-evaluate `a` and `b`?

Comment: @Bathsheba: Why not? I use them repeatedly.

Comment: Note that this algorithm doesn't do what the OP said, but rather how I interpreted what the OP may have wanted: It computes the element whose numeric value is nearest the one being searched (in the sense of its Euclidean distance).

Comment: Setting your robust reply to my question aside, this is a very good answer. I'm surprised I'm currently the sole upvoter. A specialisation exploiting the faster std::set::lower_bound would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: @Bathsheba: What specialization are you referring to? How would you write it?

Answer (score -1):

```
//included all libraries

 auto find(int l, set<int>&s){

     auto it=s.lower_bound(l);  
   
     if(s.size() and *s.begin()<=l){ //check any smaller element present in set
        
        auto it=s.upper_bound(l);
             it=prev(it);
     }   
   return it;
}
```